# Typescript error on converting type into different type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm just trying to know following error better:

> Conversion of type 'A' to type 'B' may be a mistake because neither
>   type sufficiently overlaps with the other.

Then when I tried to do some tests, I got a weird error.

These our my codes:

```
type User = {
  id: string
  username: string
  age?: number
}

const user1 = {
  id: '123',
  username: 'user',
} as User // OK

const user2 = {
  id: '123',
  username: 'user',
  age: 5
} as User // OK

const user3 = {
  id: '123',
  username: 'user',
  age: 5,
  email: '1234'
} as User // OK

const user4 = {
  id: '123',
  username: 'user',
  age: '5',
} as User // Error, the age type is different
```

These tests look straight forward.

But when I tried these:

```
const user5 = {
  username: 'user',
  age: 5,
} as User // OK even though the ID is not exist

// Weird part
const user6 = {
  username: 'user',
  age: 5,
  email: '123'
} as User // Error, when we add unknown field without Id field
`
```

Based on the `user5`, the assertion is correct. But in `user6` it doesn't which I didn't understand. Can someone here help me to understand whats going on? Thanks.

Comment: you're adding `email` in `user6` which doesn't exist in your definition. The lack of 'id' looks like it is trying to force map the structure to the type and failing. On `user3` you have a full definition _plus_ excess fields (which it looks like it's ignoring).

Comment: please check out the `strictFunctionTypes` ( can be also configured in `tsconfig` file) https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html

Comment: Should you not define type as `const user: User` instead of typecasting?

Comment: @scgough Yeah I thought so.

Comment: @Rajesh I know my sample codes are not that intuitive and you have the point. But the idea is how type assertion works on different structures.

Comment: @ymz will check. Thanks!

Comment: Great! I hope you share your insights when you are done :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless TypeScript [strict null checks](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/options/strictNullChecks.html) are enabled, `null` and `undefined` can be assigned to any type. In your `user5` test `id` is `undefined` implicitly and the compiler is happy with that.